# Publish HTML file in Azure Classic pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-marketplace, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm building a project in Azure Classic pipeline.

now i have to publish an HTML File to the tab, so i used one or more extensions ([Publish HTML Reports](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LakshayKaushik.PublishHTMLReports&targetId=503271a9-d187-4e96-8593-60cb0f08258d&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList), [HTML Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakubRumpca.azure-pipelines-html-report)).
The problem is, it doesn't publish css scripts, so that the published page is not viewing perfectly.

This is what i want

[image: result should look like this]

This is what i got 
[image: this is what i got]

Source code of both images are not same, used for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid Azure devops doesn't support publish custom HTML report yet.

There are user voices having been submitted to Microsoft development team. See user voice [Support for generic HTML Publishing inside Build and Release Pipelines](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a/491426).

You can vote up above user voice, Or [create a new user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) of your own regarding this issue.